# convert 4D .nii file to .png

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png, image-conversion, 4d

I have a 4D .nii file like "filtered_func_data.nii" from: [https://nifti.nimh.nih.gov/nifti-1/data]

By loading the data and access the img field:

```
S = load_nii('filtered_func_data.nii')
S = 

       hdr: [1x1 struct]
  filetype: 2
fileprefix: 'filtered_func_data'
   machine: 'ieee-be'
       img: [4-D int16]
  original: [1x1 struct]

A = S.img
```

with size of:

```
size(A)
```

answer =

```
64    64    21   180
```

So the data consists of 64x64 images with a depth/number of slices of 21 and a number of frames of 180. 
Can someone please help me to convert this .nii data to 21*180= 3780 png images with the size of 64*64? Also, I want to remove the last 10 slices of each time course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can remove the last 10 image volumes by [indexing the array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html#f1-86846) like so:

```
A = A(:, :, :, 1:170);
```

You'll also want to convert your data from [16-bit *signed* integers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int16.html) to [16-bit *unsigned* integers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint16.html), since [`int16`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int16.html) isn't supported for PNG files (as the error message in your comment shows). My experience with medical images like this is that the vast majority of the image data lies in the positive range, with a few spurious negative pixel values, so you'd probably be fine just zeroing out the negative values and converting to an [unsigned integer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint16.html) (you may want to look at a histogram of your pixel values to be sure):

```
A = uint16(A);  % Convert to unsigned, zeroing out negative values
```

Now, when you create all of your PNG images, you'll probably want to generate a file name that has the slice and time indices in it so you can identify and sort them easier. You can loop over every 64-by-64 image, generating a file name using [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and using [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) to create the image like so:

```
[nRows, nCols, nSlices, nTimes] = size(A);
for iSlice = 1:nSlices
  for iTime = 1:nTimes
    fileName = sprintf('%s_%d_%d.png', S.fileprefix, iSlice, iTime);
    imwrite(A(:, :, iSlice, iTime), fileName);
  end
end
```

If you'd like to cut down on the number of files you generate, you could collect the 21 slices of each image volume into a 5-by-5 mosaic, giving you one larger image (320-by-320) per time point. You can do this as follows, using [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html):

```
[nRows, nCols, nSlices, nTimes] = size(A);
for iTime = 1:nTimes
  C = cat(3, A(:, :, :, iTime), zeros(nRows, nCols, 4));  % Pad with 4 empty slices
  C = mat2cell(C, nRows, nCols, ones(1, 25));  % Place each slice in a cell
  C = cell2mat(reshape(C, 5, 5).');            % Reshape cell array and make mosaic
  fileName = sprintf('%s_%d_.png', S.fileprefix, iTime);
  imwrite(C, fileName);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it gave me this error:
Warning: Data loss and unexpected results may occur with signed pixel data. 
> In imwrite (line 447) 
Error using writepng>parseInputs (line 290)
Expected input to be one of these types: double, single, logical, uint8, 
 uint16
Instead its type was int16.
Error in writepng (line 20)
[results, unmatched] = parseInputs(data,map,filename,varargin{:});
Error in imwrite (line 472)
        feval(fmt_s.write,--
and it didnt create any png file and fileName is just 1*26 vector with one cell fill with filtered_func_data_1_1.png

Comment: @user1603454: I updated the answer to address the error.